# Why does xrandr ignore other resolutions on a 4k monitor and only list 3840x2160 available?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, xrandr, 4k-monitor

Running a Triple monitor setup, 4k on laptop left and 2 monitors on the right

When using xrandr or mate monitor, it only shows that the 4k has only 1 resolution, a 3840x2160 resolution. In nvidia-settings I can change the resolution on the 4k monitor to 1920x1080 which is what I want.

Not sure why the 4k is missing resolutions in xrandr but works in nvidia-settings.

```
$ xrandr --output DP-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
xrandr: cannot find mode 1920x1080
```

And xrandr output for current setup, DP-2 (4k) is running at 1920x1080 when I configure it via nvidia-settings.

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
DP-2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  48.02  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected 1920x1200+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to fix the xrandr issue, but I found out .config/monitors.xml that was altering my Mate settings. Removed it, and I'm back to 3 screens controlled by nvidia-settings.